# Как оправить письмо с вложением на языке Go?

Tags: golang, email

Как оправить письмо с вложением на языке Go?

Comment: Вам с помощью только стандартной библиотеки, или сторонних?

Comment: Без  разницы рассмотрю все варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот очень грубый пример отправки такого письма с почты Яндекса, используя только средства стандартной библиотеки. По хорошему, выбор границы и формирование вложения лучше доверить пакетам `mime/multipart` и `net/textproto`, плюс обработка ошибок опущена для краткости:

```golang
msg := []byte(`From: foo@yandex.ru
To: bar@yandex.ru
Subject: Hello from Go
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="XXXXXXXXXX"

Hello from Go!

--XXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"

Hello from text!
--XXXXXXXXXX--`)
msg = bytes.Replace(msg, []byte("\n"), []byte("\r\n"), -1)
host := "smtp.yandex.ru"
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", user, pass, host)
conf := &tls.Config{ServerName: host}
addr := "smtp.yandex.ru:465"
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr, conf)
cl, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
err = cl.Auth(auth)
err = cl.Mail("foo@yandex.ru")
err = cl.Rcpt("bar@yandex.ru")
w, err := cl.Data()
_, err = w.Write(msg)
err = w.Close()
err = cl.Quit()
```

Comment: А  если необходимо передать архив или xml отчет с результатами программы. Как это реализовать(передал путь до файла и по почте отправить его)